# Failed smartwatch company, new phone, cannot register app on new phone because server shut down

Tags: applications

I have an [Olio Smartwatch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01G3EHUSG) that I bought on a deal a day site last year. I has worked great up until me getting a new phone. I have to register the watch to the phone app on my new phone. In order to do this, I have to login to the olio server, which has been shut down since the company went out of business. The watch works with the old phone, but not with the new. Is there a way that I can move all of the app data to the new phone and bypass the registration? Or am I screwed?

Comment: You could try to transfer the app including its data using [tag:adb] backup. Not sure if that works out completely, but it's worth a try.